# C# Recompile a Decompiled .dll

Tags: c#, dll, compilation

So, I just decompiled a .dll using .NET Reflector. I now have a folder containing all of the .cs files (called, for example, "MyAssembly"), and subfolders functioning as sub-namespaces also containing .cs files. I edited a few of the .cs files now and want to recompile back to a .dll. Is there a way to compile the entire MyAssembly folder back into a .dll?

Comment: use Visual Studio to recompile...

Comment: Alright, so I exported the project into VS. For some reason, there are tens of thousands of errors. This can't be right- it's the code for a widely played  video game on the Steam platform. Why do you think this is?

Comment: Probably intentionally obfuscated to stop people from modifying the game and recompiling it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new C# project of the correct type (Dll, Application, etc) in Visual Studio.  The free version is available [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) if you don't already have it.  Then manually add the .cs files to the project.  If there are any resource files that the code depends on you will have to extract those also and add them to the new project.  You will probably have to add any assembly references if the code relies on anything that isn't included by default.  Once that is done you should be able to recompile the code.  There may be errors, as decompiling is far from perfect.

Comment: There's almost 30,000 errors. There's no way I can fix all of this.